# Shell with su cannot remount /sytstem. adb can.

Tags: mount, partitions, system, superuser

I am trying to mount the /system file partition in Android as rw. I have ro.insecure=0 in my default.prop. I have su installed and working correctly.
I can remount the file system using 'adb remount'
However, when I am in a shell prompt, I get a 'permission denied' error whenever I try to remount the partition. 
Why would adb remount work but remounting as root user in a shell not work?

I am using

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

I have also tried

```
mount -o remount,rw -t ext4 /system
```

but to no avail.

My default.prop has the following:

```
ro.secure=0
ro.debuggable=1
persist.sys.usb.config=adb
ro.adb.secure=0
```

Comment: How did you root and how do you know it is working?  If you're using SuperSU, trying turning off the "Root namespace separation" option.

Comment: The ROM is pre-rooted and I can install root applications. The shell gives me root access and the daemonsu process is running. I am using Superuser not SuperSU so I don't have that option.

Comment: I edited the fstab in the ROM and set it to rw. This is dirty but it works nonetheless.